# Python Django - executing django-admin-script.py - opening a file instead of create project

Tags: python, django, console, django-admin

I have got problem with django, actually with some windows 7 settings. 
I would like to create new project using command:

```
django-admin-script.py startproject NAME
```

I have added to my PATH environment variable: C:\Python33\Scripts where django-admin-script.py exists.
But when I run the above command, the file django-admin-script.py opens in Notepad++, it doesnt want to run. I have resolved that problem with the following command:

```
python C:/Python33/Scripts/django-admin-script.py startproject NAME
```

However I am a bit confused, why does the first command open the notepad instead of execute .py file? 
My default app for .py extension is Notepad++. On my laptop for default program(it has been set default itself) is set something called: Python Launcher for Windows(Console)

How can I do the same for my desktop computer? I can of course write whole second line every time, but I would rather do it simplier, like in the 1st command :)

thanks, azalut

Comment: I have fixed it already somehow. I had added association in cmd: assoc .py=Python.File and then: ftype Python.File=C:\Python33\python.exe "%1" %*   after it I have done right click and choose default program as: C:/Python33/python.exe and now the 1st command works fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `script` string. The correct command should be `django-admin.py`, which must be inside the `Scripts` directory you've added to the path.

To create a new django project, use:

```
django-admin.py startproject project_name
```

Comment: actually I noticed that my file was called django-admin-script.py :D I havent seen anything like this in the web, but it works for me :) thanks for ur answer